# javax.el.MethodNotFoundException' when invoking actionlistener

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How have to call `action` and `actionListner` from two different bean and i have added below code

```
<a4j:commandButton  id="editAlarm"  immediate="false" execute="@this" actionListener="#{cfsBean.updateCfsGroupFeature(itemsComp,tableIndex.index)}"
                                                    action="#{addFeaturePopUpBean.updateCfsGroupFeature(itemsComp,tableIndex.index)}" >
```

and Bean have this code

```
public String updateCfsGroupFeature(ActionEvent event,CompositeCharGroupVo value, Integer row) {
}
```

But i am getting

> javax.el.MethodNotFoundException' when invoking action listener
>   '#{cfsBean.updateCfsGroupFeature(itemsComp,tableIndex.index)}' for
>   component 'editAlarm'

Now [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener) **@Baluc** mentioned we can pass argument in `actionListner` as well

```
<h:commandXxx ... actionListener="#{bean.methodWithOneArgument(arg1)}" />
<h:commandXxx ... actionListener="#{bean.methodWithTwoArguments(arg1, arg2)}" />
```

Comment: Did you read the method name in example? It says two arguments, not three. The exception clearly confirms this. The desired method could not be found. The actual method has one argument too much.

Comment: Thanks Got your point

Comment: In the meanwhile, I improved that answer to eliminate confusion by starters as to method signatures when they don't read the answer's text, but only the code :)

Comment: Yes saw that..Its possible to not to call `action` if some condition fail in `actionListener`  and both call for different bean?

Comment: Scroll to bottom of answer and read last section.

Comment: @BalusC Beginners often read only the code. The basics JSF are working fine without any background skills. I just started with 'learning by doing'. But to be good at JSF, that is the wrong attempt. I really fell down with this. :)